# error when encoutering some data, but some are correct

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-processing

so i make a waging program using python, with that waging program I have an excel data that I need to processed.

my program as such

```
 # Install required library
!pip install xlrd
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time, timedelta
import openpyxl
import math
import numpy as np

# Mount google drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# Read the Excel file
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Book1.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)


# Convert the 'Tgl/Waktu' column to datetime format
df['Tgl/Waktu'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Tgl/Waktu'])

# Extract the date and time from the 'Tgl/Waktu' column
df['Date'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.date
df['Time'] = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.time

# Group the data by employee name and date
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Nama', 'Date'])

# Set the overtime threshold to 16:30:00
overtime_threshold = time(hour=16, minute=30)

# Set the late limit
late_limit = time(hour=8, minute=15)

# Set holidays date
holidays_date = ['2023-1-1', '2023-1-22', '2023-2-18', '2023-3-22', '2023-4-7', '2023-4-22', '2023-4-23', '2023-5-1', '2023-5-18', '2023-6-1', '2023-6-4','2023-6-29',
                '2023-7-19', '2023-8-17', '2023-9-28', '2023-12-25', '2023-1-23', '2023-3-23', '2023-4-21', '2023-4-24', '2023-4-25', '2023-4-26', '2023-6-2', '2023-12-26',
                '2023-1-8', '2023-1-15', '2023-1-29', '2023-2-5', '2023-2-12', '2023-2-19', '2023-2-26', '2023-3-5', '2023-3-12', '2023-3-19', '2023-3-26', '2023-4-2',
                '2023-4-9', '2023-4-16', '2023-4-23', '2023-4-30', '2023-5-7', '2023-5-14', '2023-5-21', '2023-5-28', '2023-6-11', '2023-6-18', '2023-6-25', 
                '2023-7-2', '2023-7-9', '2023-7-16', '2023-7-23', '2023-7-30', '2023-8-6', '2023-8-13', '2023-8-20', '2023-8-27', '2023-9-3', '2023-9-10', '2023-9-17', 
                '2023-9-24', '2023-10-1', '2023-10-8', '2023-10-15', '2023-10-22', '2023-10-29', '2023-11-5', '2023-11-12', '2023-11-19', '2023-11-26', '2023-12-3', '2023-12-10', 
                '2023-12-17', '2023-12-24', '2023-12-31','2022-12-20']

# Iterate over the grouped data
for (name, date), group in grouped_df:
    # Calculate the total work hours and overtime hours for each employee on each day
    start_time = group['Time'].min()
    end_time = group['Time'].max()
    total_hours = (timedelta(hours=end_time.hour, minutes=end_time.minute, seconds=end_time.second) - 
                   timedelta(hours=start_time.hour, minutes=start_time.minute, seconds=start_time.second)).total_seconds() / 3600
    if total_hours > 8:
        hours_worked = 8
        if end_time > overtime_threshold:
          overtime_hours += (end_time - overtime_threshold).total_seconds() / 3600
    elif total_hours < 8:
        if start_time > late_limit:
            hours_worked = 5
        else:
            hours_worked = total_hours
            hours_worked = math.floor(total_hours)  # Round down the hours_worked value
            overtime_hours = 0
    if end_time > overtime_threshold:
        overtime_hours += (end_time - overtime_threshold).total_seconds() / 3600
   
    # Calculate the payment for each employee on each day
    if hours_worked == 8:
        if overtime_hours > 0:
            if name == 'Alif':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'budi':
                payment_each_date = 70000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'adi':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'supriyanto':
                payment_each_date = 70000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'Edi':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'Tri Gunawan':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'Bayu Aji N':
                payment_each_date = 60000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            elif name == 'dani':
                payment_each_date = 70000 + overtime_hours * 10000
            else :
                payment_each_date = "Name Not Listed"

        else:
            if name == 'Alif':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'budi':
               payment_each_date = 70000
            elif name == 'adi':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'supriyanto':
               payment_each_date = 70000
            elif name == 'Edi':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'Tri Gunawan':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'Bayu Aji N':
                payment_each_date = 60000
            elif name == 'dani':
                payment_each_date = 70000
            else :
                payment_each_date = "Name Not Listed"

    else:
      if start_time > late_limit:
          if name == 'Alif':
              payment_each_date = 60000/2
          elif name == 'budi':
              payment_each_date = 70000/2
          elif name == 'adi':
              payment_each_date = 60000/2
          elif name == 'supriyanto':
              payment_each_date = 70000/2
          elif name == 'Edi':
              payment_each_date = 60000/2
          elif name == 'Tri Gunawan':
              payment_each_date = 60000/2
          elif name == 'Bayu Aji N':
              payment_each_date = 60000/2
          elif name == 'dani':
              payment_each_date = 70000/2
          else :
              payment_each_date = "Name Not Listed"  
      else:
          if name == 'Alif':
              payment_each_date = 60000
          elif name == 'budi':
              payment_each_date = 70000
          elif name == 'adi':
              payment_each_date = 60000
          elif name == 'supriyanto':
              payment_each_date = 70000
          elif name == 'Edi':
              payment_each_date = 60000
          elif name == 'Tri Gunawan':
               payment_each_date = 60000
          elif name == 'Bayu Aji N':
               payment_each_date = 60000
          elif name == 'dani':
              payment_each_date = 70000
          else :
              payment_each_date = "Name Not Listed"

    
    # Add the total work hours, overtime hours, and payment as new columns to the dataframe
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Hours Worked'] = hours_worked
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Overtime Hours'] = overtime_hours
    df.loc[(df['Nama'] == name) & (df['Date'] == date), 'Payment Each Date'] = payment_each_date

holiday_status = df['Tgl/Waktu'].dt.normalize().isin(pd.DatetimeIndex(holidays_date))
# make new column for holiday with boolean value then merge with the original dataframe and place it in between date and time using merge
df = pd.merge(df, holiday_status.to_frame('Holiday'), left_index=True, right_index=True)
# make the payment each date column to 1.5 times and add 5000 if the holiday column is true
df.loc[df['Holiday'] == True, 'Payment Each Date'] = df['Payment Each Date'] * 1.5 + 5000

# Calculate the total payment from payment each date and insert it into new column named Total Payment
df_total = df.groupby(['Nama', 'Date'])['Payment Each Date'].max().groupby('Nama').sum().rename('Total Payment')
df = df.merge(df_total, how='left', on='Nama')

# Print the resulting dataframe
print(df)

# write DataFrame to excel
df.to_excel(excel_writer=r'/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/test.xlsx')
```

with this [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-7Vx95ZGn9d76zbNyDSQs-aurO8iN0FN/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104401636803655793957&rtpof=true&sd=true) when I run the program it can be processed and got correct result

but when I use this [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14ZxiUY99Qmff8VzJ0SlEI1fw0lAM0PqAvexjdwCzmAM/edit?usp=sharing) I get error unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

like below
[image: Error Message]

so how do I fix it? is it the error on the data? or the program?

Comment: So what is the difference in the data? Some formatting? Extra spaces? A person’s name missing? What error trapping do you do?

Comment: thats what im confused about, what are the difference because the error only happened in the 'Tgl/Waktu' Column

Comment: I am not going to go through your data for you... Try checking for extra spaces, or numbers out of range etc etc.

Comment: The data that works probably doesn't execute the line with the error.  As the error says, you can't subtract two `datetime.time` objects, so maybe the "good" data doesn't have any `end_time > overtime_threshold`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer to make the program can run is to convert the end_time and overtime_treshold into timedelta format, such as

```
overtime_hours += (timedelta(hours=end_time.hour, minutes=end_time.minute, seconds=end_time.second) - timedelta(hours=overtime_threshold.hour, minutes=overtime_threshold.minute)).total_seconds() / 3600
```